# Get Twitter Messages Sent via SMS using Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Does anyone know of a method to collect Twitter text messages using Python (or any language)? I am working on a project and it requires a corpus made up of text messages. I thought since people use Twitter through text messages, it would be as good as collecting text messages from a phone.

Any ideas?

BTW, I have used the Tweepy library to collect the public stream of Twitter messages. However, these cannot be distinguished between text messages or just a message written from a computer as far as I know.

Comment: I believe Twitter (used to at least) display "Sent by SMS" or similar in the web-client view for a Tweet. It was placed where normally the name of the Twitter client that was used to send the tweet resided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response, look for the "source" element.

It will normally say something like

```
"source" : "<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">Some Twitter App</a>",
```

If a tweet has been sent in **via SMS / Text Message**, it will say

```
"source" : "<a href="http://twitter.com/devices" rel="nofollow">txt</a>",
```

Sadly, the Twitter search engine will *not* let you search by source, so you may have to capture a wide range of tweets in order to get enough text messages.